# DNS Tunnelling using IODINE

Tags: dns, tunnel, iodine

I'm trying to set up a DNS tunnel. I've set it up and have got to a point where the testing feature here: http://code.kryo.se/iodine/check-it/ works.

This is the result:

```
Analyzing DNS setup for tunnel domain 'tunnel.mydomain.com'... (might take some time)

Looking for nameserver for mydomain.com.. got ns.domain.com (at 208.208.208.208).
Resolving delegation of tunnel.mydomain.com at 208.208.208.208... to tunnelhost.mydomain.com (at 164.164.164.164).

Expecting iodined to be accessible at 164.164.164.164... yes, using proto 00000502.
Testing iodine reply using default nameserver... ok.

Well done, your iodine setup seems fine!
```

But when I connect from the command line, it shows this:

```
Macbook-Pro:~ user$ sudo iodine -f -P asdf -T CNAME tunnel.mydomain.com
Opened /dev/tun0
Opened UDP socket
Sending DNS queries for tunnel.mydomain.com to 82.82.82.82
Using DNS type CNAME queries
iodine: Got NXDOMAIN as reply: domain does not exist
Retrying version check...
iodine: Got NXDOMAIN as reply: domain does not exist
Retrying version check...
iodine: Got NXDOMAIN as reply: domain does not exist
Retrying version check...
iodine: Got NXDOMAIN as reply: domain does not exist
Retrying version check...
iodine: Got NXDOMAIN as reply: domain does not exist
Retrying version check...
iodine: couldn't connect to server (maybe other -T options will work)
```

Does anyone know what I can try?

Comment: I have the same problem. It would be interesting to know what query led to the NXDOMAIN response. Is there any way to debug on the client side.

Comment: @DirkJäckel that replie comes from your dnsnameserver. You can't debug so much, just server saying that this domain doesn't exist.

Answer (score 3):

for me, I needed to point the DNS requests from iodine to the server via the following:

```
sudo iodine -f -P asdf -T CNAME 82.82.82.82 tunnel.mydomain.com
```

source: manpage, 2nd to last argument

```
   iodine  [-f]  [-r]  [-u  user ] [-P password ] [-m fragsize ] [-t chrootdir ] [-d
   device ] [-m fragsize ] [-M namelen ] [-z context ] [-F pidfile ] [-T  dnstype  ]
   [-O downenc ] [-L 0|1 ] [-I interval ] [ nameserver ] topdomain
```